# Prove that the composition g ◦ f: V → U is also an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V , W, and U are vector spaces, and f: V → W and g: W → U
are both isomorphisms. Prove that the composition g ◦ f: V → U is
also an isomorphism. (Note: we use this in proving that isomorphism
is an equivalence relation, so do not use that fact here!)

I am confused on how to go about this proof. Do I just go through proving that it is one to one and onto, and preserves addition and scalar multiplicatioin? I am not sure that I understand what process to use to prove this!

Comment: You can prove separately that the composition of two linear transformations is a linear transformation, and the composition of two bijective functions is a bijective functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove this from the definition.

Linearity: Let $a,b$ be scalars and $x,y\in V$. $(g\circ f) (ax + by) = g(f(ax+by)) = g(af(x) + bf(y)) = ag(f(x))+bg(f(y)) = a(g\circ f)(x) + b(g\circ f)(y)$.

This should be enough to get you started now just check the bijective condition.